# How to append <li> to each array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html-lists

My head was overheated today.. I need help with my code. My English is not so good, so it's hard to explain my issue. So I put problem in HTML what kind of style I need to get from JS. Added `things.json` file as example, and added JS code.

```
<!-- What I'm getting: -->

<h2>Table</h2>

<ul>
  <li>brown, black, white</li>
</ul>


<!-- What I need to get: -->

<h2>Table</h2>

<ul>
  <li>brown</li>
  <li>black</li>
  <li>white</li>
</ul>
```

There's example of `things.json` file:

```
[
 {
  "thing": "table",
  "color": [
   "brown",
   "black",
   "white"
   ]
  }
  {
  "thing": "chair",
  "color": [
   "yellow",
   "black",
   "blue"
   ]
  }
  {
  "thing": "bed",
  "color": [
   "red",
   "blue",
   "green"
   ]
  }
]
```

There is example of my function:

```js
 const ENDPOINT = 'things.json' 

    async function getThing(url) { 
      const resp = await fetch(url) 
      const data = await resp.json() 
      data.forEach(appendToHtml) return data 
} 

getThing(ENDPOINT).then((value) => { console.log('getThings', value) }) 

    function appendToHtml(data) {
        const divEl = document.createElement('div')
        const h2El = document.createElement('h2')
        const liEl = document.createElement('li')
        h2El.textContent = data.thing
        liEl.textContent = data.color
        outputEl.append(divEl)
        divEl.append(h2El)
        divEl.append(liEl)

        return divEl
    }
```

Comment: First, this is not JSON; JSON is a string. How are you calling `appendToHtml()`? What are you passing in?

Comment: const ENDPOINT  = 'things.json'

async function getThing(url) {
    const resp = await fetch(url)
    const data = await resp.json()
    data.forEach(appendToHtml)
    return data
}
getThing(ENDPOINT).then((value) => {
    console.log('getThings', value)
})

Comment: Is this the actual contents of the JSON file? If so, it's invalid.

Comment: So you need to loop over the array and create multiple li elements.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your json is an array of objects (with colors) you would need 2 *levels* of loops. One for every item (object) in the array. The other for each object to build the list from its colors (that's also an array).

```js
var arr = [{
  "thing": "table",
  "color": [
    "brown",
    "black",
    "white"
  ]
}, {
  "thing": "chair",
  "color": [
    "yellow",
    "black",
    "blue"
  ]
}, {
  "thing": "bed",
  "color": [
    "red",
    "blue",
    "green"
  ]
}];

var outputEl = document.body;

function appendToHtml(data) {
  const divEl = document.createElement('div')
  const h2El = document.createElement('h2')
  const list_container = document.createElement('div')
  h2El.textContent = data.thing
  outputEl.append(divEl)
  divEl.append(h2El)
  divEl.append(list_container)
  list_container.innerHTML = appendToList(data.color);
  return divEl
}

function appendToList(colors) {
  return "<ul>" + colors.map(color=>`<li>${color}</li>`).join("\n") + "</ul>"
}

arr.forEach(function(obj) {
  appendToHtml(obj)
})
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```